# Analytics site search includes slash (/)

Tags: google-analytics

When viewing my site search reports search terms I get two results for each search-term, one ends with a slash:

```
"Contact"  65 hits
"Contact/" 60 hits
```

[image]

Can I fix this? And are there 125 total searches for the search-term or are the 60 with slashes included in the 65?
The site is [www.taby.se](http://www.taby.se)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your tracking code fires twice (at least this is what the Analytics debugger says), one without the slash and once with a slash. So your numbers are off since you double-count.

_

```
gaq.push processing "_require" for args: "[inpage_linkid,//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js]": 
ga_debug.js:24 Loading script : http://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js
ga_debug.js:24 Waiting on _require of inpage_linkid to be fulfilled.
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_require" for args: "[inpage_linkid,//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js]": 
ga_debug.js:24 Waiting on _require of inpage_linkid to be fulfilled.
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_provide" for args: "[inpage_linkid,function f(c,g){var l=/(?:^__utmli=|; ?__utmli=)([^;]*)/,d=this,m=function(a,b,d,c){var h="addEventListener",k="attachEvent";if(a[h])a[h](b,d,!!c);else if(a[k])a[k]("on"+b,d)};this.e=function(){return"; path=/"};var n=c._trackPageview;c._trackPageview=function(a){d.a();d.f&&c._setXKey(12,1,d.f);n.call(c,a)};this.g=function(){this.i||(this.i=!0,m(e,"click",function(a){d.h(a)}))};this.h=function(a){try{a=a||window.event;var b=a.target||a.srcElement;for(a=0;3>a&&!b.id&&b!=e.body;a++)b=b.parentNode;var c=
b.id||"";d.d(c)}catch(g){}return!0};this.b=function(a,b){f.prototype[a]=b};this.d=function(a){if(a&&100>a.length){a=a.replace(/[^-0-9a-z_:.]/gi,"");var b=new Date((new Date).getTime()+3E4);e.cookie="__utmli="+a+"; expires="+b.toUTCString()+this.e()}else this.a()};this.b("trackClickId",this.d);this.a=function(){e.cookie="__utmli=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT"+this.e()};this.b("deleteClickId",this.a);this.c=function(a){var b=(l.exec(e.cookie)||["",""])[1];a&&a(b);return b};this.b("getClickId",
this.c);this.f=this.c();g.disableAutoTrackLinkId||this.g()}]": 
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_require" for args: "[inpage_linkid,//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js]": 
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-29177881-1]": 
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]": 
ga_debug.js:24 Track Pageview
ga_debug.js:24 Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=5.6.2d&utms=7&utmn=577468390&utmhn=www.taby.se&utme=12(ctl00_ContentHeader_pageHeader_quickSearch_panelSearchF…ytics-site-search-includes-slash%3B&utmjid=&utmu=qAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAE~
ga_debug.js:24 Account ID               : UA-29177881-1
Page Title               : Sökresultat - Täby kommun
Host Name                : www.taby.se
Page                     : /Sok/?query=test
Referring URL            : 0
Hit ID                   : XXXXXXXXXX
Visitor ID               : XXXXXXXXXX
Session Count            : 1
Session Time - First     : Wed Jan 21 2015 14:53:25 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
Session Time - Last      : Wed Jan 21 2015 14:53:25 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
Session Time - Current   : Wed Jan 21 2015 14:53:25 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
Campaign Time            : Wed Jan 21 2015 14:53:25 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : stackoverflow.com
Campaign Medium          : referral
Campaign Name            : (referral)
Campaign Content         : /questions/28068544/analytics-site-search-includes-slash;
Link ID                  : ctl00_ContentHeader_pageHeader_quickSearch_panelSearchForm
Language                 : de
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 16.0 r0
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 2048x1152
Browser Size             : 2031x150
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.6.2d
Cachebuster              : 577468390
ga_debug.js:24 _gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[/Sok/?query=test/]": 
ga_debug.js:24 Track Pageview
ga_debug.js:24 Tracking beacon sent!
utmwv=5.6.2d&utms=8&utmn=1226977039&utmhn=www.taby.se&utme=12(ctl00_ContentHeader_pageHeader_quickSearch_panelSearchF…ytics-site-search-includes-slash%3B&utmjid=&utmu=qACAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAE~
ga_debug.js:24 Account ID               : UA-29177881-1
Page Title               : Sökresultat - Täby kommun
Host Name                : www.taby.se
Page                     : /Sok/?query=test/
Referring URL            : 0
Hit ID                   : XXXXXXXXXX
Visitor ID               : XXXXXXXXXX
Session Count            : 1
Session Time - First     : Wed Jan 21 2015 14:53:25 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
Session Time - Last      : Wed Jan 21 2015 14:53:25 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
Session Time - Current   : Wed Jan 21 2015 14:53:25 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
Campaign Time            : Wed Jan 21 2015 14:53:25 GMT 0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)
Campaign Session         : 1
Campaign Count           : 1
Campaign Source          : stackoverflow.com
Campaign Medium          : referral
Campaign Name            : (referral)
Campaign Content         : /questions/28068544/analytics-site-search-includes-slash;
Link ID                  : ctl00_ContentHeader_pageHeader_quickSearch_panelSearchForm
Language                 : de
Encoding                 : UTF-8
Flash Version            : 16.0 r0
Java Enabled             : true
Screen Resolution        : 2048x1152
Browser Size             : 2031x150
Color Depth              : 24-bit
Ga.js Version            : 5.6.2d
Cachebuster              : 1226977039
```